# Incompatibility between javax.security.cert.X509Certificate and java.security.cert.X509Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, certificate-revocation

I want to verify the X509 certificate presented by a client against a CRL to see if it has been revoked.
I have successfully instanciated a `java.security.cert.X509CRL`, but I am having problems retrieving the certificate of the session:

```
try {
    SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
    s.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_RW * 1000);
    s.startHandshake();
    SSLSession session = s.getSession();
    X509Certificate[] cert = session.getPeerCertificateChain();
    if (crl.isRevoked(cert[0])) {
        System.err.println("Attempted to stablish connection using revoked certificate");
    } else {
        ...
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong");
}
```

SSLSession belongs to the `javax.net.ssl`  package, and its method `getPeerCertificateChain()` returns a `javax.security.cert.X509Certificate[]`, which cannot be converted to the `java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]` that I need to feed the `java.security.cert.X509CRL`.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`javax.security.cert.X509Certificate` is deprecated. Get `java.security.cert.Certificate[]` by `session.getPeerCertificates();`, and then pass it to your `crl.isRevoked` implementation.

See also:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getPeerCertificateChain()
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getPeerCertificates()

> The classes in the package javax.security.cert exist for
>   compatibility with earlier versions of the Java Secure Sockets
>   Extension (JSSE). New applications should instead use the standard
>   Java SE certificate classes located in java.security.cert.

You can convert `java.security.cert.Certificate` to `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/HCiHwBKOsrI)):

```
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate.getEncoded());
    X509Certificate x509 =  (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bais);
```

Comment: The problem with that option (I contemplated it) is that later I need to use methods of X509Certificate, so it was not good enough for me.

Comment: But `Certificate` is abstract class - i bet that `cert[0]` is `instanceof` `X509Certificate` class. Just check it and cast

Comment: @user2891462 If not, you can perform conversion like this implemented `X509Certificate[] convertCertificates(Certificate[] certsIn)` method: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/HCiHwBKOsrI